# Cocoa binding vs. not synthesized property

Tags: objective-c, properties, cocoa-bindings

In my model class there is property:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSString* prop;
```

...

```
-(NSString*) prop
{ return someExternalObject.stringProp;}
-(void) setProp: (NSString*) str
{ someExternalObject.stringProp = str;}
```

At some moment `someExternalObject.stringProp` changes and I need to invoke updating of Cocoa element that is binded to `prop`. How to do it?

PS: I definitely can't bind Cocoa element directly to `someExternalObject`.

Comment: Can your model class get notified when someExternalObject.stringProp changes? The binding won't propagate the change unless the model object knows that it's there's been a change. One way to approach this is to have prop actually be a local property on your model class, and when someExternalObject.stringProp is changed, have it call [yourModelClass setProp:newValue]. This should trigger the cocoa bindings machinery.

Comment: I do similar thing at current moment: `self.prop = self.prop` in `refresh` method. But I would be happy to look at more automated solution.